# How to open message(this) on pop window

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function openpopup(pop){
  var pop1=window.open(this.pop , "", "width="+(screen.width-10)+", height="+(screen.height-10)+",hotkeys=no,scrollbars=yes");

}
</script>

<a href ='#' onClick="javascript:openpopup(showLongMessage.this)">Show More </a>
```

IT gives the following error
No route matches "/undefined" with {:method=>:get}

Answer (score 1):

Href can contain javascript that will be executed in context of opened window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openpopup(pop){
  var escaped = pop.replace(/"/g, "&quot;").replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  var pop1=window.open("javascript:document.write('" + escaped + "');document.close();",
  "", "width="+(screen.width-10)+",height="+
  (screen.height-10)+",hotkeys=no,scrollbars=yes");
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openpopup('some \'long\' &quot;text&quot;');return false;">
  Show More
</a>
```

But it is not a good way to make popups. Consider studying and using exising library.
[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for example has nice [Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the url of the page you want to open in your popup.

```
window.open('http://www.mydomain.com/mypopuppage.html','name','height=200,width=150')
```

I bet in your current code

```
this.pop
```

returns 'undefined'